# Can a first order language describe every property of the structure of its interpretation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathbf L=(C,F,P)$ be a first order language.

Let $\mathbf I$ be an interpretation of $\mathbf L$, Let $\xi(\mathbf I)$ denote the structure established by $\mathbf I$, that is $\xi(\mathbf I)=(U_\mathbf I,C_\mathbf I, F_\mathbf I,P_\mathbf I)$, where $U_\mathbf I$ is the universe of discourse of $\mathbf I$.

Is every property of $\xi(\mathbf I)$ expressible by a formula $\gamma\in FORM(\mathbf {L})$ ?

As an example:

Let $\mathbf L=(C=\emptyset,F=\{f^2,g^2\},P=\{p^2\})$.

Let I be an interpretation of $L$ such that $C_I=\emptyset,F=\{f^2(x,y)=x+y,g^2(x,y)=x-y\},P=\{p^2=\{(x,y)\in U_I:x=y\}\}, U_I=\mathbf Z$.

Is there a formula to describe that $(\mathbf Z, f^2,g^2)$ forms a group structure?

Comment: I think another way to see that the answer has to be "no" might be the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem, and in particular the consequence that any first order theory (special kind of first order language) that has a infinite model also has distinct models of arbitrary infinite cardinality. So consider $L$, and a "non-standard interpretation $I$" of $L$, then it must have properties that are not defined by a formula in $L$, because those properties are not satisfied by a structure established by a "standard interpretation $J$" of $L$.

Comment: Of course such properties of $\xi(I)$ have to be "external" (defined in the metatheory, not "internally" in $L$ itself). But that seems to be consistent with what you were asking? Anyway you might find these concepts related or interesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set ("external" concept) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions ("internal" concept), although the wikipedia articles are admittedly not the clearest / best sources to begin learning about them... Anyway I'm not an expert or great at mathematical logic, so that's why these are comments, not answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not *every* property can be described by a formula.  For instance, for any cardinal number $\kappa$, there is a property "$U_\mathbf{I}$ has cardinality $\kappa$".  There is a proper class of different cardinal numbers, so this gives a proper class of different properties.  But there is only a set of possible formulas, or even possible sets of formulas.  If your language is countable, there are even only countably many formulas, so for any uncountable collection of properties, most of them cannot be expressed by a formula.

However, in your example, the property that the structure is a group can easily be expressed by a formula, at least if you have equality as a logical symbol.  For instance, the existence of an identity element can be expressed as $$\exists u \forall x (x=f(u,x)\wedge x=f(x,u)).$$
The other axioms of a group can be expressed similarly; to get a single formula, you then take the conjunction of the formulas for each axiom.